# Configuration for Ubuntu SELinux with sshd

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, selinux

I am trying to set-up SELinux in an Ubuntu Trusty server, who is an Amazon EC2 instance. I followed the Debian documentation about installing SELinux.
The installation work well as seen by :

> root@machine:~# sestatus
>
> SELinux status:                 enabled
>
> SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
>
> SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
>
> Loaded policy name:             default
>
> Current mode:                   permissive
>
> Mode from config file:          permissive
>
> Policy MLS status:              enabled
>
> Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
>
> Max kernel policy version:      28

However, I have some problems with my context as a standard user with ssh I have the context : system_u:system_r:sysadm_t:SystemLow. 
I tested with root user, who is also system_u:system_r:sysadm_t:SystemLow.

> root@ip-172-31-4-210:~# id -Z
>
> system_u:system_r:sysadm_t:SystemLow

Since I can only join this server via SSH, I guess the problem come from that. Is their a boolean or a policy for allowing ssh login with unconfined_u context ?

**EDIT 1 :** I'm sorry I didn't give enough detail. What I want to do is just to set up SELinux for confining the process and deamon, I want my standard user to be able to sudo & be able to manage the system. 
Isn't root supposed to be in the context "unconfined_u" ? Why am I system_u ?

Output of semanage login -l:

> Login Name           SELinux User         MLS/MCS Range        Service
>
> __default__          unconfined_u         SystemLow-SystemHigh *
>
> root                 unconfined_u         SystemLow-SystemHigh *
>
> system_u             system_u             SystemLow-SystemHigh *
>
> ubuntu               unconfined_u         SystemLow-SystemHigh *

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can check all SELinux booleans with:

```
getsebool -a
```

There you can check whether there is a boolean regarding this issue or not.

Another thing you can try is giving your user a different role with:

```
semanage login -a -s <role> <your_user>
```

Just make sure the role is the same as the root user (in this case system_u), but be aware of the security risks. You can always go back with:

```
semanage login -d <your_user>
```